# Sobre o uso das tags tradução e tradução-inglês

Tags: discussion, tags

Levanto a discussão por conta [desta questão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/como-traduzir-a-express%C3%A3o-swarm-and-stick). Ela utiliza as duas tags, [tradução](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e a [tradução-inglês](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ingl%c3%aas)

Em perguntas que peçam a tradução de uma certa palavra ou expressão do inglês para o português, considere essa pergunta hipotética

> Como traduzir a expressão "go the extra mile" para o português?

além da tag [expressão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/express%c3%a3o), o correto seria utilizar:

1. Somente a tag [tradução](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) (acho improvável)
2. As tags [tradução](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e [tradução-inglês](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ingl%c3%aas) (utilizado na questão citada)
3. Somente a tag [tradução-inglês](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ingl%c3%aas) (na minha opinião, a melhor alternaitva)

O que acham?